# Stack two pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas

How do I stack the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1
    hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r
0   0           114         0
1   114         152         92.1

df2
    hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r
0   0           23          83.5
1   23          152         45
```

to give the following result:

```
    hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r
0   0           114         0
1   114         152         92.1
2   0           23          83.5
3   23          152         45
```

Using the pandas merge operations does not work since it just lines the dataframes horizontally (and not vertically, which is what I want)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
In [5]: a = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(2,5)),columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [6]: b = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(2,5)),columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [7]: c = pd.concat([a,b],ignore_index=True)

In [8]: c
Out[8]: 
    A   B   C   D   E
0  12  56  62  35  20
1  10  71  63   0  70
2  61  72  29  10  71
3  88  82  39  73  94
```

Comment: Same operation with non panda dataframes. How to do ?

Comment: @earl Generally, you should start a new thread for new questions.  However, a simple web search should find an answer and your question is likely a duplicate.  If you are using numpy arrays you can use numpy.vstack