# How merge several time series data sets to a data frame and then using cross validation on it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, cross-validation

Hi I have 50 time series datasets in 50 .CSV files and each of them have  2 column: data and label. exactly like below. each of these .CSV file contain more than 800,000 row of signal records and none of them is equal to each other

How i can merge these .CSV file in to a data frame in order to  select training and testing data with Cross validation?

because i working with RNN the sequence of data is important.

```
DATA OF CASE 1:
Data    label
23        A
88        A
56        B
87        B
56        c
87        D
17        C
44        B
12        A
----------------
DATA OF CASE 2:
Data    label
13        A
98        B
56        B
77        C
49        D
89        c
19        B
23        B
32        A
```

Comment: Do you want to stack them on top of each other as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351840/stack-two-pandas-data-frames)?

Comment: @WhoAmI no. because my data is time series and the last line of the data set case 1 shouldn't use with the first line of data set case 2, when i using cross validation.

Comment: Does each row in a file represent a time unit (e.g. day)? Or is it the whole file that is a time unit? Do you want to merge them on the label column? It would help if you show in a simple example how the end result should look like